# Rustup: error cross-compilation from Linux to Windows i686

Tags: linux, windows, rust, rust-cargo

What components installed

```
i686-pc-windows-gnu (installed)
i686-unknown-linux-gnu (installed)
x86_64-pc-windows-gnu (installed)
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
```

Rust version

```
rustc 1.17.0-nightly (08230775a 2017-02-24)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 08230775a026c955873ba557e624b7f665661f37
commit-date: 2017-02-24
host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
release: 1.17.0-nightly
LLVM version: 3.9
```

~/.cargo/config

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc"

[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc"
```

For x86_64-pc-windows-gnu compilation is okay

```
$ cargo rustc --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --release -- -C link-args=-mwindows
   Compiling ttt v0.1.0 (file:///tmp/ttt)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.21 secs
```

But for i686-pc-windows-gnu error (output too long) https://gist.github.com/bc4254bdd78195e83842682d3a432688

Mingw version

`Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /build/mingw-w64-gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-threads=posix --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-system-zlib --enable-cloog-backend=isl --enable-lto --disable-dw2-exceptions --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.1 20170109 (GCC)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I solved with [this insight](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12859) from Arnaz87.

Add this rustflag to your ~/.cargo/config

```
[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu]
rustflags = "-C panic=abort"
```